# How to display some text in pygame?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I am currently on a pygame project and wanted to display some text. I have done this before in another program and it works just fine but when I write the exact same thing in this project, it gives this error :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Fazelifar\Desktop\Dot Game.py", line 197, in <module>
>     myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 15)
>   File "C:\Users\Fazelifar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sysfont.py", line 362, in SysFont
>     return constructor(fontname, size, set_bold, set_italic)
>   File "C:\Users\Fazelifar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sysfont.py", line 285, in font_constructor
>     font = pygame.font.Font(fontpath, size)
> pygame.error: font not initialized
> ```

and here is my code :

```py
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 15)
def txt_display (txt , color , x , y):
   txt = lala.render(txt , True , black)
   main.blit(txt , (x , y))
```

plz help I am stuck

Answer (score 3):

pygame has to be initialized, before a instance of Font respectively SysFont can be created. More accurate, the [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font) modul has to be initialized.

```py
pygame.font.init()
```

But note, `pygame.init()` would initialize the `pygame.font` module, too. [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) initialize all imported pygame modules.

The name of the instance of [`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) is `myfont`, rather than `lala`. So it has to be:

<s>`txt = lala.render(txt , True , black)`</s>

```py
txt = myfont.render(txt , True , black)
```